# Connecting from Files to WifiTransfer

Tags: pantheon-files

I have an Ubuntu Phone and there's a program on there which is called WifiTransfer. It is a program to exchange files from the phone via ftp. It says that normally you would be able to see the device (on stock Ubuntu) when you view the entire network. This is not the case in Files. When I use the option in Files to connect to a server and follow the instructions to connect to the device via ftp, the error message I get is that my user data are invalid, which is not the case.

Does anyone what the reason is I can't connect to this ftp-device?